# Deep Learning models with top-down transfer

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, audio-recognition

Are there Deep Learning models that utilize some sort of top-down information transfer (not only during training)?

For example, if the model is used for speech recognition. The lower layers would listen to the samples and say: "The word 'one', the word 'two', I can't understand what this sample is". And then an upper layer would suggest: "Could it be the word 'three', that is not uncommon after 'one' and 'two'". And then the lower layers would be like: "Now that you said it! Of course it's 'three'"

I'm pretty sure that an architecture like this is a requirement for reliable speech recognition, especially in noisy environments.

Comment: There are models like this, but usually lower layers don't "go back" to refine earlier prediction based on feedback - instead they emit probabilities which are interpreted by higher layers. E.g. p('one', 'two', 'foray') is considered most likely at low level, but higher level (based on likelihood of that utterance) applies weights towards ('one', 'two', 'three') which was less likely based on individual word matching but more sensible linguistically - and will pick that.

Comment: However, I'm not sure if Deep Learning speech models do this explicitly in practice - as in someone has built such an assessment layer into them, or trained two separate models and joined them into a more complex pipeline. It may happen internally in an end-to-end model, but be difficult to show/quantify.